# base directory of script

Tags: php, twitter

i am making twitter application when i call callback.php it shows some error
here is some part of my callback.php where i think it has some problem

```
////// First establish base directory for app
define('QA_BASE_DIR', dirname(empty($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']) ? __FILE__ : $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']).'/../../');

$qainc=$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/qa-include';        //second

$piinc=$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/qa-plugin';

/* Start session and load lib */
session_start();

require_once $piinc. '/twitter-oauth-login/twitteroauth/twitteroauth.php';
require_once $piinc. '/twitter-oauth-login/config.php';
```

i want my directory url so i write second line 
www.domain.com/qa-plugin ----- i want this url but this command return this address
 "/usr/local/apache/htdocs/qa-include" 
how to correct error please help me out....

Answer (score 1):

```
getcwd(); //returns the current directory
```

[More info](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getcwd.php)

Answer (score 0):

See

`$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']`

More verbose http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Answer (score 0):

Change `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` to `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']`